# Why am I receiving this array extent error when running package code?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, package

for some reason I cannot seam to solve this one despite trying online solutions.

I am using the lovely R package EcoIndR (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EcoIndR/EcoIndR.pdf) to calculate bird community metrics for sample sites ("BUFF.1" ...) as per package instructions. The code used to work on a condensed dataset of similar extents.

My queried data looks like this, seemingly formatted exactly as per package requirements:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 125
  sp    fmly  genus forage food  nest  BUFF.1 BUFF.13 BUFF.14 BUFF.17 BUFF.22 BUFF.23 BUFF.24 BUFF.25 BUFF.27 BUFF.3 BUFF.31
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 sp1   Cist~ Apal~ glean  inve~ ball       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      1       0
2 sp103 Musc~ Cerc~ groun~ inve~ cup        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      0       0
3 sp104 Musc~ Coss~ groun~ inve~ cup        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      0       0
4 sp109 Frin~ Crit~ groun~ seeds cup        0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      0       0
5 sp11  Ploc~ Eupl~ groun~ seeds ball       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      0       0
6 sp111 Lani~ Lani~ sit&w~ inve~ nonb~      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0      0       0
# ... with 108 more variables: BUFF.33 <dbl>, BUFF.34 <dbl>, BUFF.35 <dbl>, BUFF.4 <dbl>, BUFF.40 <dbl>, BUFF.6 <dbl>,
#   BUFF.7 <dbl>, BUFF.8 <dbl>, PROT.10 <dbl>, PROT.12 <dbl>, PROT.13 <dbl>, PROT.16 <dbl>, PROT.21 <dbl>, PROT.22 <dbl>,
#   PROT.23 <dbl>, PROT.25 <dbl>, PROT.28 <dbl>, PROT.30 <dbl>, PROT.32 <dbl>, PROT.35 <dbl>, PROT.37 <dbl>, PROT.38 <dbl>,
#   PROT.40 <dbl>, PROT.8 <dbl>, PROT.9 <dbl>, RSHR.1 <dbl>, RSHR.13 <dbl>, RSHR.15 <dbl>, RSHR.16 <dbl>, RSHR.17 <dbl>,
#   RSHR.18 <dbl>, RSHR.19 <dbl>, RSHR.2 <dbl>, RSHR.22 <dbl>, RSHR.23 <dbl>, RSHR.25 <dbl>, RSHR.28 <dbl>, RSHR.29 <dbl>,
#   RSHR.3 <dbl>, RSHR.31 <dbl>, RSHR.32 <dbl>, RSHR.33 <dbl>, RSHR.35 <dbl>, RSHR.5 <dbl>, RURL.1 <dbl>, RURL.11 <dbl>,
#   RURL.12 <dbl>, RURL.13 <dbl>, RURL.14 <dbl>, RURL.15 <dbl>, RURL.16 <dbl>, RURL.17 <dbl>, RURL.18 <dbl>, RURL.19 <dbl>,
#   RURL.2 <dbl>, RURL.20 <dbl>, RURL.21 <dbl>, RURL.22 <dbl>, RURL.23 <dbl>, RURL.24 <dbl>, RURL.25 <dbl>, RURL.26 <dbl>,
#   RURL.27 <dbl>, RURL.28 <dbl>, RURL.29 <dbl>, RURL.30 <dbl>, RURL.32 <dbl>, RURL.33 <dbl>, RURL.34 <dbl>, RURL.36 <dbl>,
#   RURL.37 <dbl>, RURL.38 <dbl>, RURL.39 <dbl>, RURL.4 <dbl>, RURL.40 <dbl>, RURL.5 <dbl>, RURL.6 <dbl>, RURL.7 <dbl>,
#   RURL.8 <dbl>, RURL.9 <dbl>, RWDL.1 <dbl>, RWDL.11 <dbl>, RWDL.12 <dbl>, RWDL.14 <dbl>, RWDL.15 <dbl>, RWDL.16 <dbl>,
#   RWDL.18 <dbl>, RWDL.19 <dbl>, RWDL.2 <dbl>, RWDL.20 <dbl>, RWDL.22 <dbl>, RWDL.23 <dbl>, RWDL.24 <dbl>, RWDL.25 <dbl>,
#   RWDL.26 <dbl>, RWDL.28 <dbl>, RWDL.29 <dbl>, RWDL.3 <dbl>, RWDL.30 <dbl>, RWDL.35 <dbl>, ...
```

I load this dataframe: `traits15`, into the workspace.

I then run this:

```
DER(data = traits15, Samples = c("BUFF.1", "BUFF.13", "BUFF.14", "BUFF.17", "BUFF.22", "BUFF.23", "BUFF.24",
                                 "BUFF.25", "BUFF.27", "BUFF.3", "BUFF.31", "BUFF.33", "BUFF.34", 
                                 "BUFF.35", "BUFF.4", "BUFF.40", "BUFF.6", "BUFF.7", "BUFF.8", 
                                 "PROT.10", "PROT.12", "PROT.13", "PROT.16", "PROT.21", "PROT.22", 
                                 "PROT.23", "PROT.25", "PROT.28", "PROT.30", "PROT.32", "PROT.35", 
                                 "PROT.37", "PROT.38", "PROT.40", "PROT.8", "PROT.9", "RSHR.1", 
                                 "RSHR.13", "RSHR.15", "RSHR.16", "RSHR.17", "RSHR.18", "RSHR.19", 
                                 "RSHR.2", "RSHR.22", "RSHR.23", "RSHR.25", "RSHR.28", "RSHR.29", 
                                 "RSHR.3", "RSHR.31", "RSHR.32", "RSHR.33", "RSHR.35", "RSHR.5", 
                                 "RURL.1", "RURL.11", "RURL.12", "RURL.13", "RURL.14", "RURL.15", 
                                 "RURL.16", "RURL.17", "RURL.18", "RURL.19", "RURL.2", "RURL.20", 
                                 "RURL.21", "RURL.22", "RURL.23", "RURL.24", "RURL.25", "RURL.26", 
                                 "RURL.27", "RURL.28", "RURL.29", "RURL.30", "RURL.32", "RURL.33", 
                                 "RURL.34", "RURL.36", "RURL.37", "RURL.38", "RURL.39", "RURL.4", 
                                 "RURL.40", "RURL.5", "RURL.6", "RURL.7", "RURL.8", "RURL.9", 
                                 "RWDL.1", "RWDL.11", "RWDL.12", "RWDL.14", "RWDL.15", "RWDL.16", 
                                 "RWDL.18", "RWDL.19", "RWDL.2", "RWDL.20", "RWDL.22", "RWDL.23", 
                                 "RWDL.24", "RWDL.25", "RWDL.26", "RWDL.28", "RWDL.29", "RWDL.3", 
                                 "RWDL.30", "RWDL.35", "RWDL.36", "RWDL.37", "RWDL.39", "RWDL.4", 
                                 "RWDL.40", "RWDL.5", "RWDL.8", "RWDL.9"),Species = c"sp" , Taxon = c("fmly", "genus") ,
    TaxonFunc = c("forage","food","nest"), Index =c("Leroy", "Simpson", "D", "FRic"), file1 = "ecoIndR_output_indices_2015.txt",file2 = "ecoIndR_polarCoords_2015.txt",
    file3 = "ecoIndR_covexArea_2015.txt")
```

...and the following error is produced:

```
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Let me know if I should contact the authors rather.

Cheers.

Comment: Creating a good reprex will enhance your chances to receive appropriate help from the community: look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

After contacting author of package he found input data has to be in forms: CSV or TXT.